# What do files names like 'usbdeva.b_epX' mean on Linux after USB device got plugged in?

Tags: linux, usb, modem, gentoo

On gentoo Linux 2.6.30 I see the creation of the following character devices in `/dev/usb`, when I plug in a USB device:

```
usbdev2.8
usbdev2.8_ep00
usbdev2.8_ep02
usbdev2.8_ep81
usbdev2.8_ep82
```

My questions:

1. What do those names mean?
2. How to use this device as a serial device (as it is a USB modem capable to send AT commands or such)